# Solr auto configuration issue when spring boot actuator is enabled

Tags: spring-boot, solr, spring-data, spring-boot-actuator, solrcloud

I am working on one migration project where I am making sure Solr works fine with springboot. Howerver as soon as I enable actuator, I see solr auto configuration bean creation issues which I am unable to figure out. Please find stack trace below.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper' defined in URL [jar:file:path/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/3.0.0/springfox-spring-web-3.0.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:path/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-webmvc/3.0.0/springfox-spring-webmvc-3.0.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webEndpointServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/servlet/WebMvcEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'webEndpointServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrHealthContributor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/solr/SolrHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributor]: Factory method 'solrHealthContributor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797)

    at packagename.application.main(application.java:25)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:path/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-webmvc/3.0.0/springfox-spring-webmvc-3.0.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webEndpointServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/servlet/WebMvcEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'webEndpointServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrHealthContributor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/solr/SolrHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributor]: Factory method 'solrHealthContributor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webEndpointServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/servlet/WebMvcEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'webEndpointServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrHealthContributor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/solr/SolrHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributor]: Factory method 'solrHealthContributor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)

    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'webEndpointServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrHealthContributor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/solr/SolrHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributor]: Factory method 'solrHealthContributor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrHealthContributor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/solr/SolrHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributor]: Factory method 'solrHealthContributor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797)
    
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrHealthContributor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/solr/SolrHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributor]: Factory method 'solrHealthContributor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrHealthContributor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/solr/SolrHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributor]: Factory method 'solrHealthContributor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)
    ... 94 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrHealthContributor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/solr/SolrHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributor]: Factory method 'solrHealthContributor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributor]: Factory method 'solrHealthContributor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)
    ... 113 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2553)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 126 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What's the spring boot version? What's the solr version? What's the solrJ api version?

Comment: I am using Spring Boot (2.3.2 v) and  solrj (5.4.0 v) -- @AbhijitBashetti

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Comment: I disabled the solr health check that SpringBoot provides by default and wrote the custom health check for solr.